# A general equation for the number of rolls to get from N dice to zero dice

Tags: probability, algorithms, logarithms, dice

I am trying to understand how to write a general equation for a math problem that came up during a recent game of Warhammer 40k.

The question is:
Assume you start with a set of 10 regular 6-sided dice. The entire set of dice will be rolled simultaneously. Any of the dice that roll to a 6 will be removed from the set, and the remaining dice will be re-rolled. This will repeat until there are no dice remaining. How many rolls, mathematically, should this process take?

At first thought I was under the assumption that this would be similar to a binary search algorithm, but rather than decreasing the initial set size by $\frac 12$ per iteration, it would decrease only by $\frac 16$, though I keep coming up with answers that are clearly incorrect (huge numbers, negative numbers.)

What would be the most appropriate way to generalize an equation for this problem for a set of $N$ regular 6-sided dice?

Comment: Logic seems ok, what were your clearly incorrect answers and how did you arrive at them?

Comment: "How many rolls, mathematically, should this process take?".Are you looking for the highest probability of how many rolls does it take (exact amount of rolls) or at least an amount of rolls?

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is reasonable.  The expected number of dice is reduce by a factor $\frac 56$ each roll, so you could ask the number of rolls to get the expected number of dice below $1$.  That gives 
$$10\left(\frac 56\right)^n \lt 1\\n\approx 12.6$$
so you should expect to average $13$ rolls but that is very rough.

A more careful approach is to work upwards.  You expect $6$ rolls if you start with one die.  If you start with two dice you have $\frac 1{36}$ chance of getting two sixes and being done.  You have $\frac {10}{36}$ chance of getting one six and being at one die.  You have $\frac {25}{36}$ chance of getting no sixes and being back where you started.  If $x$ is the expected number of rolls starting with two dice you then have 
$$x=\frac 1{36} \cdot 1 + \frac {10}{36} \cdot 7 +\frac {25}{36}(1+x)\\
x=\frac {96}{11}\approx 8.73$$
You can keep going with this to get the expected value for ten dice, but the calculations get long.

Answer (score 0):

The required number of rolls is the maximum of $N$ independent identically distributed random variables with a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with parameter $p=\frac16$. The cumulative distribution function for the number $k$ of rolls required for a single die is $1-(1-p)^k$, so the cumulative distribution function for the maximum is $\left(1-(1-p)^k\right)^N$, and the expected value of the maximum is

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(1-\left(1-(1-p)^k\right)^N\right)
&=&
-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^N\binom Nj\left(-(1-p)^k\right)^j
\\
&=&
-\sum_{j=1}^N\binom Nj(-1)^j\sum_{k=0}^\infty(1-p)^{kj}
\\
&=&
-\sum_{j=1}^N\binom Nj(-1)^j\frac1{1-(1-p)^j}\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

This agrees with Ross's result for $N=2$. In your case, $N=10$, [Wolfram|Alpha yields](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20-binom%20(10,j)%20*%20(-1)%5Ej%20%2F%20(1%20-%20(1-1%2F6)%5Ej))%20for%20j%3D1..10)

$$
\frac{5002237679837182013478909216}{301979071571007691559239541}\approx16.6\;.
$$

[Here's Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/b46e32f459b70bbf73ffd568835c4199) to check the result.

Answer (score -1):

At each step you have a new geometrically distributed random variable. Each time with a different probability of success.

If you have $k$ dices, then the success ratio is $1 - \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^k$, i.e. probability of not getting every dice between $1$ and $5$.

In case $k=1$ this is our regular dice.

Now, the expectation of geometrically distributed random variable is $\mathbb{E} = \frac{1}{p}$, where $p$ - is the probability of success.

Denote $Y_i$ - a number of rolls it takes to "get rid" of a next dice, in case you have $i$ at hand.

Then $$\mathbb{E}(Y_i) = \frac{1}{1 - \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^i}$$

Since the expectation is linear 
you have $$\mathbb{E}(Y_{10} + Y_9 + \ldots + Y_1) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n = 10} \frac{1}{1 - \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^k} \approx 21.876$$

Comment: I don't see how you're using linearity of expectation here. Where does the sum over the number $k$ of dice come from?

Comment: It seems from your edit that you're not taking into account that you can get rid of more than one die per roll.